# Asyncronous server call, resource, angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm very confused. I hope you can help me.

This is my factory

```
productsFactory.getAllDiciplines = function(){
  return $resource('/api/disciplines/');
}
```

It returns an array.

This is my controller:

```
$scope.diciplines = ProductsFactory.getAllDiciplines().query();
```

This is my view:

```
<select ng-model="diciplines" ng-options="d.dp_title for d in diciplines"></select><br>
```

This works. However, when I choose an item in my selectbox. It get's empty. All items disappear. I know this has something do to with that $resource uses asyncronous calls.

How do I fix this?

Comment: you are overriding property in ng-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selected item is the whole list !

```
<select ng-model="diciplines" ng-options="d.dp_title for d in diciplines"></select><br>
```

create another property some thing SelectedDicipline  and bind it

```
$scope.SelectedDicipline  = {};
<select ng-model="SelectedDicipline" ng-options="d.dp_title for d in diciplines"></select><br>
```

Comment: Ha, thx! How embarrassing. You don't happen to know how to set the default value? As it is now it's empty.